anchor deploy does not work
I try to deploy my contract using anchor, but i get this error:
Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 61) There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.
I am using macOs

You should run test validator.
Use solana-test-validator needed.

If you are trying to use the local validator, it seems like it is not running, try these steps:

Start the local validator: solana-test-validator, on my side it requires sudo permissions, this might not be needed for you.
Deploy: anchor deploy

If you are using anchor test, it tries to start the validator itself, if you do not want that use anchor test --skip-local-validator.
If you want to use devnet, mainnet or testnet use proper RPC URL for them, you can use command: solana config set --url devnet
